# Retrieve media info from the current track being played on a specific Chromecast

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm working on a webpage controling what is being played on a specific Chromecast (there are several on the network) but I'm having trouble with the [Google Cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers).

I don't want a sender app, nor register a for an API key, just retrieve the media info currently being played.

On an Android smartphone, you get those information automatically as a notification, or directly in the Google Home application as you can see in the 2 screenshots below, even if you are not the one broadcasting the media.

[image: Automatic notification] [image: From Google Home app]

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269861/android-get-current-playing-media-on-chromecast) is talking about something similar for an Android app, but I didn't find any similar notions in the Chrome Sender API (javascript).

Using the [Chrome Sender API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/), I'm able to load a media on the chosen chromecast through a basic web app but that's not what I'm looking for. In the online documentation I did not find anything about this particular use case.

FYI the things I have:

- ReceiverApplicationId casting to the chromecast
- Chromecast IP / Name / Mac address

Does any of you have an idea how I could do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Jess, made some modifications, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this: cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession().getMediaSession() which has everything for the currently playing content including a media object which includes:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo

Comment: Does that only work if you are the sender though?